# How I can align icon next to text of MaterialButton with defined padding?

Tags: android, material-design

Hello I ran into problem with aligning icon in material button on Android. I have button with `match_parent` width, text and icon next to text. I want to align icon `8dp` left to text and I tried do it by `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` `app:iconGravity`. But result was not as expected.

[image: bad aligned icons image]

As you can see, with longer text, icon padding is smaller and smaller. I also tried define `app:iconPadding` (default is `8dp`) but with same result.

Is this bug or I'm doing it wrong?

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/MaterialButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        tools:text="L" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/MaterialButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        tools:text="Lorem ipsum" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/MaterialButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Style:

```
<style name="MaterialButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextTitleAllCapsBold</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_condensed_regular</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/padding_medium</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="iconSize">32dp</item>
</style>
```

Using `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TL;DR
>
> only use capitalized text and/or monospace fonts for buttons and use textAlignment="center" (the default) when specifying an icon with iconGravity="textStart"

I found reason and workaround how to fix this bug.
It calculates leftPadding of icon badly becouse of attribute `android:textAllCaps`.

If you have same experience, remove (or set to `false`) attribute `android:textAllCaps` and replace it with uppercased text in strings.xml or using `.toUpperCase( )` in Java or Kotlin

It is issue that was found on September 2018 and by October is marked as Fixed on Google's [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115943274). But I'm using latest stable version of library and still have the bug. Here is my [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123379514)

**UPDATE**

The bug is now fixed in version **1.1.0-alpha02**.

Answer (score 3):

remove `app:iconGravity="textStart"`

Comment: Doesn't work. I want to have icon right next to text, not not aligned left.